# missing Embed Interop Type property

Tags: .net, visual-studio, com, interop, warnings

In one C# project, I get the following warning:

> warning CS1762: A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'Interop.SomeLibrary.dll' because of an indirect reference to that assembly created by assembly 'ALibraryOfMine.dll'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly.

However, in the C# project that gives this warning, I do not see an Embed Interop Types property on the COM library reference Properties.  That's in VS 2010.  In the VS 2008 ALibraryOfMine project, the same COM library also does not have an Embed Interop Types property.  How can I get rid of this warning?  I've been getting an "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" error and I'm worried maybe differing versions of a COM library is behind it, so I wanted to eliminate COM-related errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to go to the Dll in the References, Right Click and Properites.  It is there, not on the properties of your project

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar warning once - i think this can help you; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183282.aspx.