# compile c# program with embedded dll

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-errors, advanceddatagrid

I want to ask a question about AdvancedDataGridView.dll. When I want to compile my program using AdvancedDataGridView.dll as embedded resource,

[image]

I get that error

> Error     2          Cannot embed interop types from assembly
>   'c:\Users\baristas\Desktop\AdvancedDataGridView.dll' because it is
>   missing either the 'ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the
>   'PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute
>   c:\Users\baristas\Desktop\AdvancedDataGridView.dll   Analytics

How can I fix it?

Thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090282/missing-embed-interop-type-property

Comment: not helped @MethodMan

Comment: why don't you try changing the CopyToLocal from `False to True` and remove the reference and re-add it pointing it to the bin directory. if worse comes to worse create a Dependency folder include it in your project, then copy the .dll there and add a reference / point it to that folder so that no matter where you deploy it.. it will always be there..